# Postgresql error: column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql, node-postgres

Message table from where i want to get recent contacts for 'user1', now the table looks like this:

```
| id | receiver | sender | time       |
|----|----------|--------|------------|
| 1  | user1    | host1  | 2020-07-02 |
| 2  | host2    | user1  | 2020-07-03 |
| 3  | user3    | host3  | 2020-07-04 |
```

I managed to get the expected result by using mysql:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN receiver = 'user1' THEN sender ELSE receiver END AS id, max(time) AS time 
FROM message WHERE receiver = 'user1' OR sender = 'user1' 
GROUP BY CASE WHEN receiver = 'user1' THEN sender ELSE receiver END;
```

But when i run this query on postgres i get the error: Postgresql error: column receiver must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function. Any solution to fix this problem?

Comment: Your query works as written in PostgreSQL:  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c648pLyq1N4yQTDcBMUfeM/0

Comment: yes, but when i use it on node-postgres module i get that error

Comment: Please update your question and add your node code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on ( case when receiver = 'user1' then sender else receiver end ) m.*
from messages m
where 'user1' in (receiver, sender)
order by (case when receiver = 'user1' then sender else receiver end), time desc;
```